# php unable to update specific array value

Tags: php

I am trying to compare two arrays and update specific array values based on conditions.

Getting attendance array of absent students:

```
$array1 = 
    array(
    array("student_id" => "2",
        "date" => "2016-04-24"),
    array("student_id" => "6",
        "date" => "2016-04-24"));
$attendance = json_decode(json_encode($array1));
```

Getting student list array of all students:

```
$array2 = 
    array(
    array("student_id" => "1",
        "Reason" => "",
        "date" => "2016-04-24"),
    array("student_id" => "2",
        "Reason" => "",
        "date" => "2016-04-24"),
    array("student_id" => "3",
        "Reason" => "",
        "date" => "2016-04-24"),
    array("student_id" => "6",
        "Reason" => "1",
        "date" => "2016-04-24"));
$students = json_decode(json_encode($array2));
```

Taking out only student IDs of absent students:

```
foreach($attendance as $att) 
{   $atts[] = $att->student_id;}
```

Here I am trying to find out if any of the students ID in student array matches with ID in absent array. If ID is present then I will update the Reason as "1". Else will make the reason as 0

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($students); $i++) {
    if(in_array($atts[$i],$students))
    {
        $students->Reason='1';
    }
    else
    {
        $students->Reason='0';
    }
} 
echo '<pre>',print_r($students,1),'</pre>';
```

Here I am unable to update student array with "reason" values.

Comment: `json_decode(json_encode($array1));`.. whut?

Comment: Hey Jon I am new to php and and was trying to convert multi dimensional array to array of std objects

Comment: Okay, first off, just use the arrays. You have no benefit in this use-case of converting to objects. 2) `$students` is an array, not an object, so doing `$students->Reason` doesn't even make sense as you're actually wanting to update `$students[$i]`? 3) $students is an array of either more arrays, or currently in your case, objects. Your `in_array` is currently trying to compare a scalar value (an ID) against an array or object, which isn't going to match.

Comment: OK. Please suggest a way out

Comment: I usually wouldn't do this, but I've done a little cleaning up and refactoring to what I believe works the way you want (see https://3v4l.org/b5fce). It's only an example using your code as a basis. Please have a read and understand what the differences and changes are before using :).

Comment: still not getting the desired output. Reason is still not getting chaged

Comment: You can see from the link I posted reason IS getting changed. So no idea what the heck you're doing with it.

Comment: Sorry Jon. Your code is working absolutely fine. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to compare `student_id` from `array1` with `student_id` from `array2`, and set `Reason` in `array2` if they correspond to each other, use this :

```
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($value1['student_id'] == $value2['student_id']) {
            $array2[$key2]['Reason'] = 1;
        } else if ($array2[$key2]['Reason'] != 1) {
            $array2[$key2]['Reason'] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I am increasing array elements in both arrays, the code doesnt work

Comment: Did you increase with another array ? Show me what you have now

Comment: I have made changes in my original question. Added arrays in both array1 and array2

Comment: My bad, I modified my post.